# aws-amplify/ui-reac, Is possible to redirect after sign in

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

Hello I'm trying to redirect and change my path after sign in using AWS-amplify and with react-dom

I need after user login redirect them to `localhost/main` main because its sill in `localhost/`

If anyone have an idea can help me thank you
My Code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import {
  AmplifyAuthenticator,
  AmplifySignUp,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from "@aws-amplify/ui-components";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import Main from "./main";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const AuthStateApp = () => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
      setAuthState(nextAuthState);
      setUser(authData);
    });
  }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/main">
          <Main />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  ) : (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator>
      <AmplifySignUp
        slot="sign-up"
        formFields={[
          { type: "username" },
          { type: "password" },
          { type: "email" },
        ]}
      />
    </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
};

export default AuthStateApp;
```

Answer (score 1):

after search about this issue the solution is to make your own design for login and register using `AUTH.signIn()` and `Auth.signUp()` and you can redirect after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using angular but I think it could be similar

```
  onAuthUIStateChange((authState, authData) => {
            console.log('LoginPage', authState, authData);
            if (this.authState == AuthState.SignedIn) {
                this.router.navigate(['']);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this:

1. wrap the `<router>` with `<AwsAuthenticator>`, a component that you will use to check the and require authentication.
2. At AwsAuthenticator.tsx (or js if you are not using typescript) you will do this:

```js
// @ts-ignore
import {Authenticator} from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import React, {ReactNode, useState} from 'react';
import {signUpConfig} from '@app/components/Authentication/SignUpForm.config';

interface AwsAuthenticatorProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const AwsAuthenticator = ({children}: AwsAuthenticatorProps) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // possible states: signIn | signedIn | signedOut
  const handleAuthStateChange = (authState: string) =>
    authState === 'signedIn' ? setLoggedIn(true) : setLoggedIn(false);

  return loggedIn ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Authenticator
      usernameAttributes="email"
      signUpConfig={signUpConfig}
      onStateChange={handleAuthStateChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for amplify v5 there is a solution:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Hub.listen("auth", (data) => {
      if (data?.payload?.event === "signIn") {
        router.push("/");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, but it will redirect you to /main everytime you refresh the page, not only after login.

Just import the react-router-dom hook useNavigate, set it to a variable and then call it inside the useEffect

See it implemented in your code

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import {
  AmplifyAuthenticator,
  AmplifySignUp,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from "@aws-amplify/ui-components";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import Main from "./main";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const AuthStateApp = () => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
      setAuthState(nextAuthState);
      setUser(authData);
      navigate("/main");
    });
  }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/main">
          <Main />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  ) : (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator>
      <AmplifySignUp
        slot="sign-up"
        formFields={[
          { type: "username" },
          { type: "password" },
          { type: "email" },
        ]}
      />
    </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
};

export default AuthStateApp;
```